# How to encode a dictionary of Codables in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, encoding, codable

I have a `[String: Codable]` dictionary in Swift that I want to save into user defaults, but I'm struggeling to do so.

**I've tried converting it to `Data` using**

```
try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
```

But this crashes ("Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)")

**I've tried using `JSONEncoder`:**

```
JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)
```

but this will not compile ("Generic parameter T could not be inferred").

Of course I could manually transform all my Codables into [String: Any] and then write it to user defaults, but since the whole point of Codable is to make Decoding and Encoding easy, I'm not quite sure why the two solutions above are not possible (particularly the second one)?

**Example**:

For reproducibility you can use this code in a Playground:

```
import Foundation

struct A: Codable {}
struct B: Codable {}

let dict = [ "a": A(), "b": B() ] as [String : Codable]
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
```

Comment: This works for me in a playground: `struct My: Codable {}; let dict = ["hello": My(), "world": My()]; let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)`

Comment: Could you show your struct and all relevant code, so that this is reproducible?

Comment: Unfortunately not since it is company code, but I think your example works because it's a homogenous collection. `[String: My]` works, but `[String: Codable]` does not work. So `let dict = ["hello": My(), "world": Yours()]` will not work. I can provide an example playground if necessary.

Comment: I've added example code to the question

Comment: `Any` isn't `Codable`. You will somehow need a way to make your dictionary homogeneous.

Comment: No, but `Codable` is `Codable`, so if I have a `[String: Codable]` dictionary (not `[String: Any]`) this should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Codable is a generic constraint here that can't be encoded

Comment: You can use a wrapper type, see for example https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-encode-objects-of-unknown-type/12253/5 (and then do for example `JSONEncoder().encode(dict.mapValues(AnyEncodable.init))`) – though I would strongly advise reconsidering whether `[String: Codable]` is the strongest type that can represent your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Codable`, as a generic constraint, and `Any` are not encodable. Use a struct instead of a dictionary:

```
struct A: Codable {
    let a = 0
}
struct B: Codable {
    let b = "hi"
}
struct C: Codable {
    let a: A
    let b: B
}

let d = C(a: A(), b: B())
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(d)
```

Comment: No offense but I was almost going to post this as an answer. I just finished writing and your's one popped up 

Comment: yeah guess this makes sense :D a bit of a shame that we have to create a named entity for this, but what you gonna do. thanks! PS: Sorry @nayem :D

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults has a way to save [String: Any] dictionaries:

```
let myDictionary: [String: Any] = ["a": "one", "b": 2]
UserDefaults.standard.set(myDictionary, forKey: "key")
let retrievedDictionary: [String: Any] = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "key")!
print(retrievedDictionary)      // prints ["a": one, "b": 2]
```

However, if your dictionary is a property of an object that you want to save to `UserDefaults` you need to implement the `Codable` protocol for your object. The easiest way I know is to convert the dictionary to a `Data` object using `JSONSerialization`. The following code works for me:

```
class MyObject: Codable {

    let dictionary: [String: Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.dictionary = dictionary
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dictionary
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if values.contains(.dictionary), let jsonData = try? values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .dictionary) {
            dictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [String: Any]) ??  [String: Any]()
        } else {
            dictionary = [String: Any]()
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if !dictionary.isEmpty, let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary) {
            try container.encode(jsonData, forKey: .dictionary)
        }
    }
}
```

To save and retrieve `MyObject` from `UserDefaults` you can then do this:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func set(_ value: MyObject, forKey defaultName: String) {
        guard let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(value) else { return }
        set(data, forKey: defaultName)
    }

    func myObject(forKey defaultName: String) -> MyObject? {
        guard let data = data(forKey: defaultName) else { return nil }
        return try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: data)
    }
}
```